# Haskell, how to print value and return in function

Tags: haskell, iteration

I try to write custom function which take an array and iterate it, i need to print every digit and recursive launch the same function but i get error

> parse error on input `main'

code:

```
firstitem n = if n /= [] n firstitem( tail n )


main = do
    print(firstitem [1,2,3])
```

Comment: What bad in my question? It totally defined.

Comment: I think that the *unexplained* downvotes on this question are a bit harsh.

Comment: This question shows complete ignorance of Haskell's fundamental concepts (no sign of IO monad in a function that is required to print something; ignorance of haskell's `if-then-else` syntax and semantics) and moreover lack of common sense: if you want to print something recursively, you need to put `print` into the recursive function (it's should be obvious even for imperative programmers).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first problem is that you have the wrong syntax for an `if` statement. You should write

```
firstItem n = if {- condition-}
    then {- do this -}
    else {- do that -}
```

Second, it's not clear what the function `firstItem` is supposed to do. It sounds like it's supposed to return the first item of a list, but your description makes it seem as though you want to iterate over all elements of the list.

You can combine the iteration and printing into a single function like this:

```
printAll xs = if null xs        -- If the list is empty
    then return ()              -- then we're done, so we quit.
    else do print (head xs)     -- Otherwise, print the first element
            printAll (tail xs)  -- then print all the other elements.

main = printAll [1,2,3]
```

The function `null` returns `True` if the list is empty, otherwise it returns `False`. The statement `return ()` you can think of as saying "there's nothing more to process, so stop the function now and return no result". The third and fourth lines contain a "do block". The do block is basically a bit of glue that binds the two actions `print (head xs)` and `printAll (tail xs)` together into one action. You can write it with curly braces to make it a bit clearer:

```
do {
  print (head xs);
  printAll (tail xs)
}
```

although you don't actually need them - the indentation specifies what you mean.

This solves your problem, but it's a bit clunky. Haskell is supposed to be a beautiful language, after all - so let's make your code beautiful! It would be better to use pattern matching to pull the list apart into its head and tail:

```
printAll []     = return ()
printAll (x:xs) = do print x
                     printAll xs
```

That's a lot better. But it could be more modular. Hey, maybe we could make a generic function that takes an action as input, and does that action for every element of the list:

```
repeatedly f []     = return ()
repeatedly f (x:xs) = do f x
                         repeatedly f xs

printAll xs = repeatedly print xs
```

That's neat. But actually, there's already a function that does this. It's called `mapM_` (there is a good reason for it being called this, but I won't get into it now) and it's in the `Control.Monad` module:

```
import Control.Monad

printAll xs = mapM_ print xs
```

Actually, you can leave off the `xs` argument, and the compiler can infer that it's supposed to be there:

```
printAll = mapM_ print
```

Finally, your code is beautiful. Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell an `if` always needs to have an `else` branch as well. You are also missing a `then`, i.e. you need something of the form `if CONDITION then TRUE_VAL else FALSE_VAL`.

You could avoid the `if` altogether by using pattern matching.

To print out progress during execution you could use the [`Writer` monad](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more).

Comment: I need do nothing in "else" statement, what i should do?

Comment: The `else` branch also needs a value. Moreover, what kind of value is `n firstitem( tail n )` supposed to be? Like that it is just wrong.

Comment: I need to print(return) n value and recursively call same function, how to accomplish that?

Comment: @testCoder: I updated the answer regarding that. You should however try to learn the basic syntax first, otherwise you will very soon be lost.